# GWT Datagrid selective refresh of some columns and not others

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.4

Hi I have created a GWT datagrid, which has 10 columns. Of these 4 columns are for user entered data, and the rest are values loaded from a database. I have implemented a timer that refreshes the datagrid every 2 seconds. Here -

```
        final Timer timer = new Timer() {
        public void run() {
            refresh();
            schedule(2000);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(2000);
```

the `refresh()` function calls the `dataProvider.refresh()` in my dataProvider implementation.

However, my requirement is to only update the 6 columns regularly, while the user entry columns should only be updated when the user presses the "enter" key or an update button.

Is it possible to selectively refresh some columns periodically and some others based on user action?

Thanks and regards

Mukul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is only possible to refresh the whole `DataGrid` and not only specific columns.   However you could always extend the DataGrid and implement this functionality yourself.
You can check out following classes:

- [HasDataPresenter](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/HasDataPresenter.java)
- [AbstractHasData](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.java)
- [AbstractCellTable](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.java)

Comment: Tried extending the datagrid, but i was wondering if there is any other method to do this in GWT

Comment: As far as I know in GWT 2.4 this is the only way. Maybe they added some additional features to GWT trunk (2.5) which allows further customizations. However when as of it is now, when the underlying data is refreshed the entire CellWidget is redrawn.